# Create glusterfs Distributed-Replicated

Tags: glusterfs

I'm new to glusterfs, it would be much appreciated if someone can explain glusterfs Distributed-Replicated setup.

If i have 2 node each with 3 physical disk inside,  each physical disk size is 1 TB,  i want to create replica of 2, may i know the command below correct ?

gluster volume create test-volume replica 2 
node1:/exp1/brick1 node2:/exp2/brick2
node1:/exp1/brick3 node2:/exp2/brick4
node1:/exp1/brick5 node2:/exp2/brick6

below is what i expecting :

- usable space is 3 TB
- replica 3TB
- node1:/exp1/brick1 is replicated with node2:/exp2/brick2
- node1:/exp1/brick3 is replicated with node2:/exp2/brick4
- node1:/exp1/brick5  is replicated with node2:/exp2/brick6
- expect to local self-mounts ( with client connect ) either from node 1 or  node 2

  Is my above expectation valid ? using Gluster 3.8.

between according to this side (https://brainpan.io/wiki/GlusterFS_Build_Steps), it emphasize "This distribution and replication would be used when your clients are external to the cluster, not local self-mounts."

Appreciate for any advice/guide.

Thanks.
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've done is right. You might get faster responses if you ask gluster related questions  on #gluster on freenode or gluster-users@gluster.org